# How to set only one NULLABLE out of two input fields

Tags: laravel

I have two input fields one as mobile_no and other as email, i want to set a condition that out of two fields if mobile_no is not given them email must be required and vice versa.

How to set nullable condition on laravel validation that only one field out of two must be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom rule. So your need is opposite of what `required_if` rule does, so please try this one and let me know.

First create custom rule, I call it `NullableIf`

```
php artisan make:rule NullableIf
```

Then the implementation should be something like this:

```
class NullableIf implements Rule
{

    private $otherField;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct( $otherField )
    {
        $this->otherField = $otherField;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        if($this->otherField === null) 
        {
            return $value !== null;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The validation error message.';
    }
}
```

To use it you do:

```
$request->validate([
    'field1'                 => [ new NullableIf(request('field2')) ],
    'field2'                 => [ new NullableIf(request('field1')) ]
]);
```

I hope at least it gives you direction unless this exact implementation does not suits your needs.